# MS Access Tab Control Name with Number of Records

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am developing an Access database (using Office 2016) and have several tab controls which I want to display the number of records in the subform/subreport.

After a lot of searching etc I have it working for the subforms using a function which I call in the main forms current event (but in a seperate function so I can also call via a macro when I change the main forms record with a combo box, as it wasn't updating otherwise). The code I am using is:

```
Function ClientTotals()

Dim i As Integer
i = Form_sbfrm_ClientContacts.Recordset.RecordCount
Form_frm_Clients.ClientTabs.Pages("Contacts").Caption = "Contacts (" & i & ")"
End Function
```

This works perfectly for me and my tab name becomes "Contacts (No. of records)" but I can't get the syntax right to change this to work for a report, is it possible?

I have tried:

```
Function ClientTotals()

Dim i As Integer
i = Form_sbfrm_ClientContacts.Recordset.RecordCount
Form_frm_Clients.ClientTabs.Pages("Contacts").Caption = "Contacts (" & i & ")"

Dim j As Integer
j = Report_rpt_CurrentProjects.Recordset.RecordCount   ' this line is highlighted with the debugger
Form_frm_Clients.ClientTabs.Pages("Current Projects").Caption = "Current Projects (" & j & ")"

End Function
```

As well as:

```
Dim j As Integer
j = rpt_CurrentProjects.Report.Recordset.RecordCount  ' this line is highlighted with the debugger
Form_frm_Clients.ClientTabs.Pages("Current Projects").Caption = "Current Projects (" & j & ")"
```

and various others.

Another question I have is why is the syntax for the form "Form_sbfrm" etc    and not using a "!". If I change to "!" it bugs out.

Thanks for your help, KAL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recordset if you need to return complex data, if you need one value, a total or a sum, Domain functions are the way to go.  Don't overdue them though, having too many on a form or a report can start to bog down usability.

Glad I can help.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Delecron,

I think I will stick with the tabs for now as they are giving me exactly what I want, but remember what you have said for when I make future improvements if its a better way of doing it.

**EDIT**

Using what you have said I changed my VBA to a DCOUNT method:

```
Dim j As Integer
j = DCount("*", "qry_CurrentProjects", "FK_Project_Client_ID = Forms!Navigation!Navigationsubform.form!Client_ID")
Form_frm_Clients.ClientTabs.Pages("Current Projects").Caption = "Current Projects (" & j & ")"
```

This means my report tabs are now also working just how I wanted

I was getting in a muddle with the criteria/filter, hense the edit.

If Recordset is an old method I am assuming it would be best to replace my other code with the Dcount method?

Thanks again, KAL

**Further EDIT**

After doing this I could see that everytime the form was changed there was a slight flicker. Not bad but you could see there was a lot of calculation going on. Therefore I have changed my method to the following, and posted here for anyone looking at this in the future.

In the form footer a textbox with COUNT([Project_ID])

In my function

```
Dim j As Integer
j = Form_frm_Clients!rpt_CurrentProjects.Report!txt_CurrentProjectsCount.Value
Form_frm_Clients.ClientTabs.Pages("Current Projects").Caption = "Current Projects (" & j & ")"
```

Now I can see it is working quicker with no flicker.

Answer (score 0):

Recordset.Recordcount is a legacy feature that only worked in ADP files (Access front end's to a SQL database).  Those are no longer supported.

If the report is based on 1 client only and there is no grouping then you can do this:

Click on the detail section and in Events create an event for On Paint.  In there set

```
(Name of Page).Caption = DCount("*", "NAME OF QUERY/TABLE") or
(Name of Page).Caption = DCount("*", "NAME OF QUERY/TABLE", "Filter Expression") (Filter expression optional).
```

If the report is grouped where it will show a different page per client or date range or any other grouping this will not work since the Caption field is not data bound.  You would have to add logic to the Dcount statement above to field by the current filter condition.

For example, say you have a database of 200 clients and you're running one big report on all of them, each page will get its own tab control per client, the syntax would be

```
(Name of Page).Caption = DCount("*", "ClientContacts, "ClientID = " & ClientID)
```

The better way to do it especially if you are grouping is get rid of the tab control and use databound controls.  You could create a box around the information that would be in the tab page and put a textbox where the tab would go.  Create a group header for however you are grouping the data.  Create another invisible textbox in the group header and set the controlsource = Count([fieldname]) where fieldname is whatever you are grouping the data by (the inside brackets count).

Then in the textbox you created to simulate the tab, set the controlsource to the name of the invisible textbox.

Let me know if this helps.